# How can I report a bug about `nautilus` conveniently

Tags: nautilus

How can I report a bug about `nautilus` conveniently (without creating an account or signing in).  If you want to know about bugs you want to make it convenient right?

Here is a description of the bug...

[link to an askubunut.com question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1462795/padlock-on-directory-icons-may-be-missing)

Comment: If you wish to report bugs, firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: If you're using a *development* release, you can use #ubuntu-next forums/sites including IRC, where others will note what you report, and if they can re-create it write the report for you. Your linked question though is for a rather old release (~six *stable* releases ago from *development* now) thus will only get security fixes in most cases; with `universe` packages in their last days of *guaranteed* support anyway.   If it was reported & discovered in *lunar* whilst in *development*  (now *final/RC* so only installer bugs are in focus now) it maybe fixed & backported to the LTS (22.04)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: "*without creating an account or signing in*" suggests that the reporter wants to fire-and-forget the report; to not answer questions from bug triagers about how to reproduce or about their setup or offering to help try fixes. That often results in closed/incomplete bug report that waste the (precious) time of triagers and developers. Rather like remaining outside a restaurant while hungry; stepping in and briefly interacting is much more likely to achieve the desired result.

Comment: fyi:  I mentioned IRC in my prior comment; but you can also use some other platforms too, eg. *matrix*, *telegram* in specific rooms, as well as *discord* & elsewhere too; for *development* releases though.  Many platforms do require login so you must comply with rules of the service; but IRC is an example of one that can be used using only a web browser too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, no. You can sign up/in to Launchpad to file bugs there. Similarly upstream projects like GNOME (where Nautilus originates) have a bug tracker you can sign up/in to also.

While we do want people to file bugs, we also want to get *useful* bug reports and limit spam. It's a well-known fact that if you leave bug report systems wide open, two things will happen:

1. You'll get a lot of spam which humans need to manage, or write bots to manage - a colossal waste of time that could better be spent elsewhere.
2. You'll receive a glut of completely useless bug reports.

Indeed, even *with* a mandatory sign-up process you *still* get many (although many fewer) spam and useless reports.

Comment: Yes, I guessed that. BTW: The launchpad.net comments are off topic because they require a sign-in.  Sometimes signing into launchpad.net is enough to make me not report the bug. This is a bug I've known about for years. Anyway I posted it to launchpad.net today.

Comment: Frankly, if you want it fixed, the absolute best thing to do is file the bug where the developer requests.  You've now had the time-attention of four people on this question. Imagine how much more efficient it would be to just go and file the issue :)